# User was not successfully retrieved. Seeing if this is a system account

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-service

I have created a user profile programmatically in SharePoint with the `accountname "i:0#.f|gdwmembershipprovider|NTI3ODI0OQ=="`

The profile was successfully created. I can also visit the user profile page (mysite profile page). I'm the administrator with 'manage profile' permission in User Profile Service and hence I can edit the profile even though I'm not logged in with the same account.

But when I click on edit link on the profile page "Sorry, something went wrong" message is displayed. Then I find the error in ULS. Here are the messages I see:

> User was not successfully retrieved: i:0#.f|gdwmembershipprovider|NTI3ODI0OQ== in ProfileUI.OnInit. Seeing if this is a system account
>
> User i:0#.f|gdwmembershipprovider|NTI3ODI0OQ== not found and not a system account.
>
> ProfileUI: Unhandled exception inside OnInit: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserNotFoundException: i:0#.f|gdwmembershipprovider|NTI3ODI0OQ==     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileUI.OnInit(EventArgs e)

Please note: When I try to create a profile through Central Admin UI, I'm not able to. The server belongs to a domain called "abc.com". While creating the profile it does not resolve `"i:0#.f|gdwmembershipprovider|NTI3ODI0OQ=="` which is as expected. But programmatically I can create the profile.

What could go wrong in editing the profile?